# jQuery regex over multi-line (dotall)?

Tags: jquery, multiline

I am having difficultly targeting, capturing and replacing some BBCode (to HTML) that is spanning over several lines.

Specifically the `[QUOTE]` tags..

I have read/searched and understand there is no dotall in javascript/jQuery, and to use the `[\s\S]` or the `[^]` instead..  but I cant seem to figure it out.

Example string  (text from an XML node)

```
<![CDATA[

[QUOTE=SOMENAME]Well I tell ya what .....
Sounds like a great project.
[/QUOTE]

[url]http://www.randomlink.com/something/[/url]

[url=https://www.another site.com/user/xxxxxxx]Sent from my whatever[/url]

[URL="http://www.somesite.com/"]http://www.somesite.com//[/URL]

]]>
```

I have tried over and over at regex101.com to see if I could stumble upon it.. but I could never quite get it right.

I need to target the `[quote]` `[/quote]` section..

capturing the "SOMENAME" in the `[QUOTE=   ]` portion.. as well as the text between the two `[quote]` tags.

this doesnt get FULL MATCH but gets me the initial tag and the first group1 capture of the SOMENAME

```
\[quote=(.*?)\]
```

this goes too far and into the next element/node, as well as the wrong group2 capture:

```
\[quote=([\s\S]+?)\](.*)\[
```

How can I correctly target JUST the quote section and capture the two groups correctly as well.. when it spans over multi-lines like that?

**edit/update:**

well looks like I fumbled my way to a working regex solution.

Posting to share with others how this approach worked for me.  (I'm sure other ways to do it?)

but for targeting/capturing content that spans  multiple lines.. I used this regex:

```
\[quote=(.*?)\]([^\[]+)\[\/quote]
```

---

**However, if anyone can help out with multiple NESTED quote tags and how to replace them... that is appreciated.**

---

- Yes I understand regex probably isnt the best way to go about this.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex could be like this:

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/K5hIqf/4/)

```
(?:\[QUOTE=)([^\]]+)\]([^\[]+)(?:\[\/QUOTE\])
```

- **`(?:\[QUOTE=)`** matches `[QUOTE=`, where **`?:`** means "non-capturing group".
- **`([^\]]+)`** matches anything that's not a closing square bracket **`]`**.
- **`\]`** matches a closing square bracket **`]`**.
- **`([^\[]+)`** matches anything that's not an opening square bracket **`[`**.
- **`(?:\[\/QUOTE\])`** a "non-capturing group" which matches `[/QUOTE]`.

[**jsFiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/xkd8t0xq/1/)

---

#### Update/Edit:

Now for matching multi *nested* `[quote]` tags and converting them to HTML, it'd be easier if you break the above regex into two parts. first part replaces all occurrences of opening `[QUOTE=SOMEONE]` and replace it with `<blockquote>SOMEONE:`.

And the second part will replace all `[\QUOTE]` tags with `</blockquote>`.

[**jsFiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/g5zxonh2/4/)

```js
var btnProcess = document.getElementById('process');

btnProcess.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var data = document.getElementById('data-txt').value;

  data = data.trim().replace(/\r|\n|\r\n/g, "<br>");
  data = data.replace(/(?:\[QUOTE=)([^\]]+)\]/gi, "<blockquote><strong>$1:</strong><br>");
  data = data.replace(/\[\/QUOTE\]/ig, '</blockquote>');
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = data;
});
```

```css
blockquote {
  margin: 10px; padding: 5px; background-color: #eee; border: 1px dashed grey;
}
blockquote blockquote { background-color: #f1f1f1; }
blockquote blockquote blockquote { background-color: #f5f5f5; }
```

```html
<textarea id="data-txt" rows="5" cols="50">
[QUOTE=SOMEONE]Well I tell ya what .....
Sounds like a great project.

[QUOTE=anotherone]
[QUOTE=firstone] I need help with regex[/QUOTE]
I am going to make it!

and it'll be great
[/QUOTE]

I am excited too.
[/QUOTE]
</textarea><br>
<button id="process">Process</button>
<hr>
<strong>Result:</strong><br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: HA!  I was thinking the same thing.  Just do 2 separate replaces for the open and closing tags.. (instead of making it harder on myself).

I also think I might need to do this same approach for my other replacement lines (bold, underline..etc) to account for mullti-line'ness.

Accepted answer.

Comment: Well, you don't always need to use 2 steps for each tag, first you can match [all BBcode](https://www.bbcode.org/reference.php) closing tags with this **`\[(\/[a-z]+)\]`** https://regex101.com/r/4z3rbv/3/ .. also if you modify it to be **`\[(\/?[a-z]+)\]`** https://regex101.com/r/4z3rbv/2/ this will capture both opening and closing tags in one search for the *straightforward* tags, meaning the ones without attributes.

Comment: However you now are facing three problems, first one is the opening tags which have attributes, especially the one with more than one attributes. Second problem is there could 2 versions of the same tag, i.e `[img width={width} height={height}]{url}[/img]` vs `[img={width}x{height}]{url}[/img]` and `[color={color}]{text}[/color]` vs `[style color={color or hex}]{text}[/style]`

Comment: The third problem is that most BBcode tags are either deprecated or non HTML, *deprecated* like **`i`** and **`b`**, and *NON-HTML* like **`right`**, **`left`**, **`color`** and **`youtube`**, in both cases you'll need to replace each one of them also convert some of them into css style attribute **`style=..`** .. it'll be a little long journey so enjoy it :)